# Re-ordering between two atomic loads

Tags: c++, memory-barriers, stdatomic, seqlock

I have the following program:

```cpp
int normalData[2];
std::atomic<int> counter {0};

// thread A:
// write new data
normalData[(counter + 1) % 2] = newData;
counter.fetch_and_add(1, std::memory_order_release);

// thread B:
auto before = counter.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
auto tmp = normalData[before % 2];
auto after = counter.load(?);
bool success = (before == after);
```

Each time thread A writes a new value, the counter is incremented. The `std::memory_order_release` ensures that the data has been written before the counter is incremented. On the other hand, thread B wants to read the data and loads the counter with `std::memory_order_acquire`. This ensures that the reading of the data cannot start before thread A has written the data. So far everything works fine. But to see if the read data is valid, the counter is loaded a second time. But how can I prevent the second load from being executed before the data is actually read? Usually the second load must have `std::memory_order_release`, which is forbidden for load operations. So how can I prevent that the code gets reordered to this:

```cpp
// thread B:
auto before = counter.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
auto after = counter.load(?);
auto tmp = normalData[before % 2];
bool success = (before == after);
```

Finally, I want to ensure that the read data was not altered by a simultaneous write operation.

## Update

is this a solution?

```cpp
// thread B:
auto before = counter.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
auto tmp = normalData[before % 2];
bool success = counter.compare_exchange_strong(before, before, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
```

Comment: Is your goal to be sure that the data read by B has not been modified by A after the first load? Or that you cannot write a new value while you have not read the first one? In this case, I think that you'll need some synchronisation mechanism on A side more than a second load on B. Could you clarify your actual goal (and not how you try to achieve it)? thanks.

Comment: I think is technically UB no matter what you do with the second load. Because when the second thread does `normalData[before % 2]`, the first thread can run two iterations and try to write to the same array element at the same time, resulting in a data race. Not sure how much of a problem this is in practice, though.

Comment: i m not sure but in a first reading i think that [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) would help.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat should not be a problem in this case, since `after` should not be equal to `before` and the result will be discarded.

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper unfortunately I need an lock-free implementation :/

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, what you describe is called a SeqLock. These are a bit bothersome when it comes to the C/C++ memory model. See for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419723/which-of-these-implementations-of-seqlock-are-correct

Comment: The direct answer to your question would probably be to have a `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);` directly before the second load (and then you can make the second load relaxed), because you want to ensure that all reads after the acquire fence don't get reordered before the fence, and hence before the non-atomic reads. I'm still not quite sure whether the full algorithm idea of yours is then formally correct (this is not a standard atomic pattern, and reasoning correctly about the memory model is hard), so I'm not going to put this as an answer, but just as a comment here.

Comment: @Homer512: Yes, it looks a lot like the seqlock pattern, although they're using 2 buffers here to reduce the number of stores in the writer.  (With only one writer, it doesn't have to be an atomic RMW, just `counter.store(counter.load()+1, release)`, which would be a much bigger speedup).  It also makes it lock-free; there's no point where the writer could block/sleep that would leave the reader spinning indefinitely.  Of course, if `int normalData[]` is really just `int`, a plain `atomic<int>` would be way more efficient.  (With `relaxed` or `release`/`acquire` as needed.)

Comment: [Implementing 64 bit atomic counter with 32 bit atomics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54611003) is my attempt at saying something about the fact that a seqlock relies on detecting a race after it happened, which is UB in C++ but I think not something a compiler can plausibly notice and compile time and break your code.  You want to avoid defeating its ability to `memcpy` with wide loads / stores.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the non-atomic `int normalData[2]` from two threads is in general a data race (and hence undefined behaviour) *even if* you accurately detect the fact that the race happened afterwards and discard the value.

For `std::atomic<int> normalData[2]`, even a relaxed load of `normalData[before % 2]` will happen after the first acquire load of `before` because it's sequenced after it in the same thread.  If it was also an acquire load, it would happen before the second load of the counter, which is the hard part.  (`std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire)` between those two loads would also work, and in practice on most implementations will work even for a non-atomic payload.)

As discussed in comments, if the payload is small enough to be lock-free `atomic`, it's not obvious why you're doing this in the first place (maybe there should be a long, speculative computation between loading the data and checking whether it's still valid).

As also discussed, this particular UB is probably perfectly well defined on most specific platforms - just not by the standard.

Comment: It's not dependency-ordering (`memory_order_consume`) that's relevant here, although that would be sufficient for keeping the first counter load ahead of the payload.  It's actually an `acquire` load so just being sequenced before is sufficient even without a data dependency.

Comment: If the payload really is just one `int`, this whole SeqLock-like scheme is pointless and they should just use `std::atomic<int> payload` with `relaxed` or `acquire` and `release` loads, unless they actually need a sequence number with it.  Making the payload `atomic<>` makes a SeqLock less efficient; compilers won't optimize multiple small values to a wide vector copy that isn't guaranteed atomic, and `atomic<big_struct>` will use a spinlock. See [Implementing 64 bit atomic counter with 32 bit atomics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54611003) - detecting a race after it happens works in practice.

Comment: I don't think the CAS_strong workaround is guaranteed safe; see [For purposes of ordering, is atomic read-modify-write one operation or two?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65568185) - that shows the store side of an atomic RMW reordering with a later relaxed store. The same is probably true for the load side with an earlier non-atomic load. It also defeats a lot of the benefit of this scheme, making the readers not read-only anymore so read-side scalability is gone: readers will contend with each other for ownership of the cache line.

Comment: Your edit was closer but still not quite right; I fixed it for you and added a sentence that answers the actual tricky part of the Seqlock pattern (and this question), about ordering the second counter load *after* the payload load.

Comment: Nice one, thanks!

Comment: @PeterCordes I think the situation is different. In your example it is an `x.exchange(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)` followed by a `y.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)`. The relexed-store can therefore cross the release-store of the exchange. In my example, however, it is an ordenary store followed by a CAS. So if the CAS write was successful, there must be a release-store to ensure that the data is stored in `tmp`. Imaging the value of the counter has really been changed. In this case, it must be synchronised with other acquire-operations in other threads which might use `tmp`. Or not?

Comment: @HansD: In Thread B you have an ordinary *load* from `normalData[before % 2]` followed by a CAS(acq_rel), which doesn't guarantee the plain load happens before the load side of the CAS.  It's the same in theory as the store side of an acq_rel RMW reordering with a later relaxed store.  (And neither can happen on x86 where the RMW is also a full barrier.)  `tmp` is a local var; it doesn't matter if or when it's value ever ends up in memory; it can live in a register, and the release-store side of the CAS doesn't change that because `tmp` is a local whose address hasn't escaped the function.

Comment: @HansD: Interesting idea, though, to force program-order of the load and store to be before the CAS by maybe passing the address of `tmp` to some opaque function, instead of using `asm("" :: "r"(&tmp) : "memory")` or something.  But that still wouldn't guarantee that runtime reordering with the load side of the CAS couldn't happen.  It can't reorder with the release-store side of the CAS, but could with the acquire-load side, so that doesn't help except on x86 where compile-time ordering is all we need to take care of.  Runtime matters, hence `atomic_thread_fence` not `atomic_signal_fence`.